# Two bitmaps both 24bmpRGB. 1st 256 x 176 with white color and blank. 2nd 140 x 40 with English text on it. how to copy 2nd into middle of 1st

Tags: image-processing, bitwise-or

*Below code is for 1st image that I generated and saved. Second image is located on my disk*

```
Bitmap lcdScreen = new Bitmap(256, 176);

        for (int line = 0; line < lcdScreen.Height; line++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < lcdScreen.Width; col++)
            {
                lcdScreen.SetPixel(col, line, Color.White);
            }
        }
        Bitmap clone = new Bitmap(lcdScreen.Width, lcdScreen.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        clone.Save(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\OCR\" + "tempImage.bmp");
```

Comment: well you copy the pixels from image 2 into image 1 using a positional offset that you calculated from the different dimensions? what exactly is your problem?

Comment: @Piglet By positional offset you mean that I need to find difference of height and width from larger image to smaller and divide them by 2?